# Facebook loading wrong og tags

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I followed this guide
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

I can see all those 5 tags on my site, but when I use the Facebook debugger, it sees completely different tags.

Any reason why this might be happening?
I scraped it like billion times, I have meta tags on 4 different sub pages and all of them working correctly, but this one does not.

Answer (score 0):

So after a while I realized that the og:url was pointing to a site which required login, so the Facebook bot couldn't get there and load the correct tags. Oh wel...:)